# resolveClass doesn't resolve symbolic references

Tags: java, classloader

JLS says that resolveClass method should verify all symbolic links

> This specification allows an implementation flexibility as to when linking activities
>   (and, because of recursion, loading) take place, provided that the semantics of the
>   Java programming language are respected, that a class or interface is completely
>   verified and prepared before it is initialized, and that errors detected during linkage
>   are thrown at a point in the program where some action is taken by the program
>   that might require linkage to the class or interface involved in the error.

So I tried to create class T that references another class in the first project and created the second project with a custom class loader loads class T but not load another referenced class.

```
public class T {
    public static AnotherClass field = new AnotherClass();
}
```

```
public class AnonClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public Class findClass(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(str));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Class<?> aClass = defineClass(null, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        return aClass;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {
        AnonClassLoader anonClassLoader = new AnonClassLoader();
        Class<?> aClass = anonClassLoader.loadClass("/Users/root/IdeaProjects/untitled/T.class", true);
        System.out.println(aClass.getName());
    }
}
```

So I expect to get NoClassDefFound as soon as possible, but the actual result - no errors are thrown, class resolved successfully

Answer (score 0):

So, according to 
Bug ID: [JDK-8057777 Cleanup of old and unused VM interfaces](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8057777) 
there is no static resolving in the hotspot.

Meanwhile, in [hotspot](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l732) jdk 8 native function has no implementation